# How to use cocoapods with a Flutter plugin?

Tags: dart, flutter, cocoapods

*First, I would like to say that I am not a iOS developer*.

I am trying to develop a VLC plugin for Flutter. For so, I need to add its pod (pod "MobileVlcKit") to a podfile, right?
But when I create the project (via the command `flutter create -t plugin flutter_vlc_kit`), the iOS folder inside the project has no podfile.

Also, it does not have any of the .`xworkspace` or .`xcodeproj` files that I can open on XCODE for  code editing:

[image]

How can I add the vlc kit dependency pod (pod "MobileVlcKit") to this plugin?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add your pod dependency modifying your `ios/flutter_vlc_kit.podspec`

```
s.dependency 'MobileVLCKit'
```

or with the wanted version

```
s.dependency 'MobileVLCKit', '3.2'
```

References:

- [Flutter Plugins](https://flutter.io/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#ios)
- [Cocoapods](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#dependency)

Then go to your `example/ios` folder and run `pod install`.

Then open your `Runner.xcworkspace` and build your plugin from there.

*Note:* probably you could encounter this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685) - tl;dr (not the best choice) change the build system of XCode to the legacy one.

Comment: So, I did what you jsut said, but I still can't see the MobileVLCKit inside my fluter_vlc_kit/ios folder. Just inside the flutter_vlc_kit/example/ios. There is something I am missing here?

Comment: @DanielOliveira  Nope it’s right. You have to code your plugin from the example project. A fast way to open your plugin file from there is cmd+shift+o and then type your filename.

Comment: Wait, I don't code my plugin into the "SwiftFlutterVlcKitPlugin.swift"? (this file is inside the flutter_vlc_it/ios)

Comment: @DanielOliveira It’s also in the example project from which you ara able to code, build and test it.

Comment: @DanielOliveira It’s the same file ;-]

Comment: If I add "import MobileVLCKit" inside my swift file, it complains with "No such module 'MobileVLCKit' ... :'(

Comment: Well I actually didn’t try with MobileVLCKit, but I could give it a try once in front of a PC. Btw I suggest you to try playing with your plugin without pods. Maybe put only a log. Then add a very simple pod and try using it. And when you are confident try VLCKit again [-;

Comment: @DanielOliveira Be aware also that some pods need extra setting to be used on a swift project. So I suggest you to play around also with an objective-c plugin. Just to see if you can use a pod with it and not in a swift project you need to figure it out why. I know, that’s too much things but if you wanna get your hands dirty with plugin development you need a bit inside on the native side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187281/discussion-between-daniel-oliveira-and-shadowsheep).

Comment: Hi!! Did you managed to use pods inside a plugin package? Cheers

Comment: One more thing if you get some errors like `The 'Pods-Runner' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries` while `pod install`, include `s.static_framework = true` to the podspec file.